# FloatingActionButton placed above another 2 widgets

Tags: android, android-layout, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

Using the Lollipop version of Android (v5.0) and following Material Design guidelines, I figured out how to create a FloatingActionButton using an `ImageButton` tag and elevation.

How is it possible to get the effect of the button sitting between (and on top) of 2 other widgets?

```
     widget A
---------O---------  <<<<  button is placed on top where widget a and b meet
     widget B
```

I am stuck, anyone have some example XML?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using a `RelativeLayout`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML, you can use a `FrameLayout` or a `RelativeLayout` to overlay widgets like buttons and other views. 
Quick example using FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#88AAAA" />

<View
    android:layout_marginTop="108dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="#AA88AA" />

<!-- Your fab button -->
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    android:layout_marginTop="68dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Result:

[image: FrameLayout to overlay views]: